# Ansible playbook using date.stdout filter with variable from stdout

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run this task:

```
---
- name: "{{ BANNER }}"

  shell: "rpm -qf /etc/issue"
  register: rpm
  changed_when: False
  ignore_errors: True

- shell: 'rpm -q -i "{{ rpm.stdout }}" | grep "Install Date:" | awk ''{ print $4 " " $5 " " $6 }'''
  register: rpm
  changed_when: False
  ignore_errors: True

- shell: 'date -d "{{ rpm.stdout }}" +''%Y-%d-%m'''
  register: date
  changed_when: False
  ignore_errors: True

- debug: var=date.stdout

- debug: var={{ (( date.stdout | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) - ("2020-12-25" | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days  }}
```

Basically I need to pass the string contained in data.stdout to filter to_datetime for date subtraction but I receive this error:

```
TASK [RH7-008 : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.56.1] => {
    "date.stdout": "2019-14-03"
}

TASK [RH7-008 : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.56.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ([u'check_mode']), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: time data '2019-14-03' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/roles/RH7-008/tasks/check_mode.yml': line 27, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug: var={{ (( date.stdout | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')) - (\"2020-12-25\" | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d'))).days  }}\n  ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n\nexception type: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>\nexception: time data '2019-14-03' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible/main.retry
```

It seem's that the format input contained in `date.stdout` is wrong compared to the one that is specified in `to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d')`. What am I missing? Maybe there's some strange character in `date.stdout` ?

Thanks in advance!
Tommaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking `to_datetime` to parse dates of the form `%Y-%m-%d`.

You are passing in data of the form `2019-14-03`.

There are not 14 months in the year.

You want the format argument to `to_datetime` to match the format argument you're providing to the `date` command:

```
to_datetime('%Y-%d-%m')
```

Making it (reformatted slightly for clarity, and with the hardcoded date swapped to match your format):

```
- debug:
    var: >-
      (
      (date.stdout | to_datetime('%Y-%d-%m')) -
      ("2020-25-12" | to_datetime('%Y-%d-%m'))
      ).days
```

Alternatively, swap the argument to the `date` command instead if you really wanted `%Y-%m-%d`. Just make sure they match.

Comment: Thank you for your help it was a silly mistake but i really didn't notice :)